# What does "bullet biting" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "bullet biting" mean here? Is it related to "Bite the bullet"?

> Union theorists have responded to this objection in several ways. Nozick (1989) seems to think of a loss of autonomy in love as a desirable feature of the sort of union lovers can achieve. Fisher (1990), somewhat more reluctantly, claims that the loss of autonomy in love is an acceptable consequence of love. Yet without further argument these claims seem like mere **bullet biting**. Solomon (1988, pp. 64ff) describes this “tension” between union and autonomy as “the paradox of love.” However, this a view that Soble (1997) derides: merely to call it a paradox, as Solomon does, is not to face up to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yet without further argument these claims seem like mere bullet biting.

This does mean 'bite the bullet' but not exactly. Out of several descriptions about the idiom, it's meaning in this context comes close to what's described in **McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.**

> [Bite the bullet](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bite+the+bullet) - *to accept something difficult and try to live with it.*

The author might mean to say that all previous verdicts/opinions seem more like compromising with the situation (loss of autonomy in love). S/he then puts Solomon's view that describes the tension between union and autonomy as 'the paradox of love'. Further, Soble derides it and clarifies that it's not to face up to the problem.

Comment: What other meanings does this idiom have? (I found three wordings on the page you have linked to, but I wouldn't call those three different meanings. They are essentially three different phrasings of the same meaning.)

Comment: @J.R. the portion of *try to live with it* where it gives a note of compromise probably.

Comment: Ah, so one allows for _trying_, while the other two take Yoda's view on the idiom: [Do or do not. There is no try.](http://www.estevanvega.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/yoda-do-or-do-not-there-is-no-try.jpg) I see, now. Glad I asked.

Comment: I *still* don't see any significant difference in meaning. Biting the bullet *always* means accepting the [inevitable] pain associated with some [inevitable] remedial action. The fact that OP's citation implies an *optional* remedy (compromise which the writer doesn't agree with) doesn't mean the idiom itself has that extended meanikng - it's just that the writer has used it somewhat loosely.

Comment: @Fumble - I don't see any _significant_ difference in meaning, either, but at least I now understand what Maulik meant by "of the three, this meaning comes closest". (I do the same thing, sometimes, when I'm looking for a definition to include in one of my answers; I pick from the dictionary that best fits the nuance I'm describing, even though all the definitions I've examined pretty much mean the same thing.)